# Trying to populate form field with autocomplete from 2 different arrays

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I have a form with 2 fields "what" and "area". I have auto-complete working when there are 2 arrays, one for each field however i need the first field "what" to use data from 2 different arrays. Is this possible?

```
//This works
<form........
<input name="what" id="what" type="text" size="45" />
<input name="area" id="area" type="text" size="45" />
......form/>

<script>
var tags = [ <?php do { ?>"<?php echo $row_rsCategories['category']; ?>",<?php } while ($row_rsCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategories)); ?> ];
$( "#what" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
return matcher.test( item );
}) );
}
});
</script>
<script>
var tags3 = [ <?php do { ?>"<?php echo $row_rsDirectory['suburb']; ?>, <?php echo $row_rsDirectory['postcode']; ?> ",<?php } while ($row_rsDirectory = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDirectory)); ?> ];
$( "#area" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
response( $.grep( tags3, function( item ){
return matcher.test( item );
}) );
}
});
</script>
```

//This doesn't work

```
<form........
<input name="what" id="what" type="text" size="45" />
<input name="area" id="area" type="text" size="45" />
......form/>

<script>
var tags = [ <?php do { ?>"<?php echo $row_rsCategories['category']; ?>",<?php } while ($row_rsCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategories)); ?> ];
$( "#what" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
return matcher.test( item );
}) );
}
});
</script>
<script>
var tags2 = [ <?php do { ?>"<?php echo $row_rsKeywords['keyword']; ?>",<?php } while ($row_rsKeywords = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsKeywords)); ?> ];
$( "#what" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
response( $.grep( tags2, function( item ){
return matcher.test( item );
}) );
}
});
</script>
<script>
var tags3 = [ <?php do { ?>"<?php echo $row_rsDirectory['suburb']; ?>, <?php echo $row_rsDirectory['postcode']; ?> ",<?php } while ($row_rsDirectory = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDirectory)); ?> ];
$( "#area" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
response( $.grep( tags3, function( item ){
return matcher.test( item );
}) );
}
});
</script>
```

I have tried changing form field id="what" to class="what" and changing $( "#what" ) to  $( ".what" ) to no avail.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with the code you need working? It seems php is not needed here. I mean in this particular example.

Comment: OK will create it now

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KtsXx/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to join 2 arrays and use autocomplete for one of resulting array.
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KtsXx/)
But you can use [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) property of jqueryui autocomplete:

```
.autocomplete({source: function(request, response){
    var res = getDataBySearchTerm( request.term );
    response( res );
}});
```

You can have a look on how to use it [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple)